# savedInstanceState is null and onSaveInstanceState is not getting called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment, state

I've done my due diligence and checked all the answers on SO around that, incorporated suggestions but for some reason none of the methods for save and restore are getting called.

An answer suggested that I should have save at the activity level in order for the fragment save state to be called, so here's my activity

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)
        supportActionBar?.title = "My App"
    }

    // not called
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
    }

    // not called
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    // not called
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

My Fragment is as follows.

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    // savedInstanceState is null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    // savedInstanceState is null
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View { 
    }

    // not getting called.
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(bundle: Bundle) { 
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle)
        bundle.putSerializable("users", arrayListOf()) // user array
    }
}
```

So not sure what am I missing here for the state to be saved and restored.

How am I testing? I press back button to home screen to push the app in the background and then bring it to the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called by the system to save the current state of the activity to make sure when users resume the app they will see the activity when they left before (by calling `onRestoreInstanceState()` to restore the state of activity). It will be called in the following conditions:

- Users move from an activity to another activity
- Users press the Home key to bring the app to the background
- When configuration changed, like users rotate the phone or change language, etc.

In your case, because you press the Back key, so the system knows that you want to leave the activity, so no need to save the state of that activity, that why you never see `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` get called.

Comment: a bit of improvement, on pressing home button (not back) Fragment's `onSaveInstance` got called, but where do I read/restore the values within fragment again?

Comment: In fragment, you can red data from bundle inside `onCreate(Bundle)`, `onCreateView(Inflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` or `onViewCreated(View, Bundle)`.

Comment: Also the ``Bundle`` in ``onCreate`` will be null if there's no state to be restored, i.e. if the ``Activity`` is starting "fresh". This basically happens when the user leaves the activity intentionally, including hitting the back button (backing out of it) or swiping the app away in the task switcher (explicitly closing it)

Comment: @AppDeveloper You can simulate a case when the system saves and restores an activity by go go Developer options -> turn on Do not keep activities. Then open the app  -> press Home to bring the app to the background ->  Open the app from the background.

Comment: is it possible to turn on do not keep activities on the emulator, couldn't find the option. I enabled developer mode on the emulator.

Comment: Yes you can, just go to Settings, find or search an option named `Build number`, then tap on it (5-7 times), until you see the message like "You enabled Developer options".

Comment: yes i enabled it, but I still don't see developer options, searched, i tapped again twice and it says you are already a developer. Emulator is pixel 2.

Comment: Go to `System -> Advanced -> Developer options`

Comment: I wanted to stress out the part @SonTruong said about  "the system knows that you want to leave the activity, so no need to save the state of that activity". 

My problem was i called finish() after changing activity, after removing finish(),  onSaveInstanceState() get called!